# Definition of page load for WP-Cron?

Tags: wp-cron

My site is extremely low traffic for the time being. For the sake of this question, let us assume it is *no* traffic.

I have a .php file on my server which is executed every five minutes via crontab on the server.
The file contains this code:

```
<?php
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://page url");
curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

?>
```

As far as Wordpress is concerned, is each visit by the above code considered a “page load”, such that WP-Cron is kept alive for the tasks scheduled within it?

I notice in the stats plugin I use, nothing is recorded for the url visits I specified in the code.

Assuming this has no effect on whether WP-cron remains alive, and an actual browser visit is the only legitimate “page load”, what solution is available??

Thanks much for all responses!

Comment: Yes, that counts as a page load, but you shouldn't need this PHP file. Just have your cron command visit /wp-crong.php: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/

Comment: I can’t tell you how much I appreciate that. Problem solved!